# Преобразование и приведение типов

Tags: java, терминология

Чем отличается преобразование типов от приведения типов?
Относятся ли autoboxing/unboxing к преобразованию или приведению?

Comment: Синонимы. Ничем, короче

Comment: [Приведе́ние (преобразование) ти́па](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0)